# mod_rewrite: query string gets lost on rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have limited .htaccess knowledge and requires some help. I need to redirect all page request to www.newdomain.com except for www.olddomain/page.json but the query string get dropped when it redirect. how can i preserve it? thankyou very much!

Current code:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/page.json
RewriteRule (.*) http://newdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Edit: Just to make it clear, i only need to stay on page.json on the old domain, lets say user request for www.olddomain.com/page1.json?session=gVgr30ExUlM
i need to redirect to
www.newdomain.com/page1.json?session=gVgr30ExUlM
BUT when it is www.olddomain.com/page.json?=LKJHGF i need it to stay on that old domain and wont redirect is it possible?

Comment: "PLZ HELP URGENTLY" is not a good title to begin with.

Answer (score 3):

Use the [`[QSA]`](http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RewriteFlags/QSA) flag ("query string append")

Comment: You did not mention that you were talking about `POST`. This is not a query string but the request body which gets lost on a *redirect* (`[R=301]`). You will also note that the request to newdomain.com after redirect is a `GET` request. You simply cannot redirect post requests as post requests to another server.

Comment: My bad, so how should i go about doing it

Comment: Ask yourself: Do you really have to worry about someone sending a POST request to the old URL? All forms will already point to the new URL, right?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add [`[QSA]`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsa) and optionally [`[NE]`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/flags.html#flag_ne) which should give you:

```
RewriteRule (.*) http://newdomain.com/$1 [QSA,NE,R=301,L]
```